# processing immediate text box value

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Is it possible to have a text input field which displays somewhere else (e.g. in a div) what its content is on change?

Example: I type 1, so 1 is outputted somewhere on my screen immediatly, then I type 2 and the previous value is now updated to 12.

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="inputField" />
<div id="screen"></div>
```

**script**

```
document.getElementById('inputField').onkeyup = function(){
document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = this.value;
};
```

The code is good but I want the screen's inner html value to be format in php. Example: the screen value is stored into $screen and then I'd echo the output where i want into the screen

[I want (echo "$screen";) like in php I will type the number in text box means it echo the value immediately used with php format]

***how to store a screen value into variable $screen***

Comment: Please phrase your questions better in the future. I've edited it now for clarity, but it was very hard to understand what exactly you were asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html  >
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function KeyHandler() {
            var result = document.getElementById('result');
            result.innerHTML=document.getElementById('txtInput').value;

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body >
<div>Type something.........</div><br />
<input type='text' id='txtInput'onkeyup="KeyHandler()" />

<br/>
Result:
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by little javascript code, (assuming that you need to display text entered in a input field on a html div),
So try this in html,

```
<input type="text" id="inputField" />
<div id="screen"></div>
```

and bind a [onkeyup](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) event to the input field by which you can get the text when someone enters into it. So your javascript will be,

```
document.getElementById('inputField').onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = this.value;
};
```

Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NUXDT/) and you can post the input field value to any php script by including a form element in your html code.

Comment: the answer is good but i want screen inner html value for php format example on screen value that stored into $screen then echo the output where i want into the screen

Comment: Do you want to display entered input value in another php file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="addInput" />
<div id="showdata"></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('input#addInput').on('keyup',function(){
   $('div#showdata').html($(this).val());
});
```